# Filtering on pattern using NOT deprecated

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When I write a cypher query with [**Filter on patterns using NOT**](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#filter-on-patterns-using-not), the Neo4j browser shows the following warning:

```
This feature is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.

Coercion of list to boolean is deprecated. Please consider using `NOT isEmpty(...)` instead.
```

My query is:

```
MATCH (a)-->(b)
WHERE NOT (b)-->(a)
RETURN a, b
```

Is there a better way to write this query, so it works in future Neo4j version?

Answer (score 1):

You could be using `NOT exists()`.

For a given

```
CREATE (b:User{name:'B'})-[:ANY]->(:User{name:'A'})-[:ANY]->(b)<-[:ANY]-(:User{name:'C'})
```

Your query returns:

```
╒════════════╤════════════╕
│"a"         │"b"         │
╞════════════╪════════════╡
│{"name":"C"}│{"name":"B"}│
└────────────┴────────────┘
```

If you use

```
MATCH (a)-->(b)
WHERE NOT exists((b)-->(a))
RETURN a, b
```

It also returns

```
╒════════════╤════════════╕
│"a"         │"b"         │
╞════════════╪════════════╡
│{"name":"C"}│{"name":"B"}│
└────────────┴────────────┘
```

but uses the `exists(Pattern)` clause that is not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Both isEmpty() and exists() function/predicate will work.

```
MATCH (a)-->(b)
WHERE NOT IsEmpty((b)-->(a))
RETURN a, b

OR

MATCH (a)-->(b)
WHERE NOT exists((b)-->(a))
RETURN a, b
```

Comment: `isEmpty` yields "A pattern expression should only be used in order to test the existence of a pattern. It should therefore only be used in contexts that evaluate to a boolean, e.g. inside the function exists()" That's why I excluded it from my answer.